# Sobrecarga de funciones en Python?

Tags: python, funciones, sobrecarga

Necesito saber si es posible en python, como en Java, sobrecargar una funcion, es decir, invocar una funcion con una cantidad diferente de parametros. Por ejemplo, si me pasan un IVA variable, invoco a la funcion que recibe el IVA variable, si no, invocar a la que usa el 21% fijo

```
def facturacion(cantidad,iva):
   return cantidad * (iva/100)

def facturacion(cantidad):
   return cantidad * 0.21
```

Me da el error

TypeError: facturacion() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Revisa la documentación para `*args` y `**kwargs`. Aparte de eso tienes también los parámetros opcionales: `def facturacion(cantidad, iva=0.21)`

Comment: Ya, gracias. Leyendo la informacion de *args lo que hice fue controlar la cantidad de parametros de la funcion y en dependencia de la cantidad de parametros retornar una cosa u otra                                                    def facturacion(*params):
    if len(params)==1:
        return params[0]*0.21
    else:
        return params[0] * (params[1]/100)

Comment: Para tu caso quizá optaría por parámetro opcional, la verdad. Se me hace un poco raro. Sería tan sencillo como definir la función con `def facturacion(cantidad, iva=21):` y simplemente devolver `return cantidad * (iva/100)`

Answer (score 2):

Por supuesto, observa estas 3 funciones:

```
def func1(a, b=21): # Función con un parámetro default
    print(a, b)

def func2(a, *b): # Recibe múltiples argumentos no indexados
    print(a, b)
    
def func3(*args, **kwargs): # Múltiples argumentos, indexados y no indexados
    print(args, kwargs)
```

Llamando a esas funciones:

```
func1(10) # 10 21
func1(10, 50) # 10 50
func1(b=10, a=50) # 50 10 (asignación posicional)
#
func2(10) # 10 ()
func2(10, 50, 70, 80) # 10 (50, 70, 80)
#
func3() # () {}
func3(10, 50) # (10, 50) {}
func3(10, 50, mon='lun', tue='mar') # (10, 50) {'mon': 'lun', 'tue': 'mar'}
```

En las documentaciones es muy común toparse con la notación de `*args, **kwargs`, pero es solo una convención, le puedes poner como quieras. Los asteriscos son [operadores de desempacado](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+unpacking+operator).